# Como dar formato a texto de un json para mostrarlo en un Data Table

Tags: php, html, ajax, datatables

Resulta que estoy haciendo un sistema y estoy utilizando Ajax y PHP para realizar todas las acciones a la base de datos y todo me funciona perfecto, pero tengo un campo de descripción que quiero mostrar en una tabla.

El texto es algo largo y no se me ajusta a la celda de mi tabla.

Ya probé modificando el CSS pero no me respeta ninguna clase de estilos.

¿Cómo puedo ajustar ese contenido?

Acá el código de mi proyecto

Ajax que me trae los datos de una consulta

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var articuloId, opcion;
    opcion = 4;
    tablaArticulos = $('#tablaArticulos').DataTable({  
        "ajax":{            
            "url": "./bd/c_articulos.php", 
            "method": 'POST', //usamos el metodo POST
            "data":{opcion:opcion}, //enviamos opcion 4 para que haga un SELECT
            "dataSrc":""
        },
        "columns":[
            {"data": "articuloId"},
            {"data": "nombre"},
            {"data": "descripcion"},
            {"defaultContent": "<div class='text-center'><div class='btn-group'><button class='btn btn-primary btn-sm btnEditar'><i class='fas fa-edit'> Editar</i></button><button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm btnBorrar'><i class='fas fa-trash-alt'> Eliminar</i></button></div></div>"}
        ]
    });
```

Código PHP que Realiza la Consulta

```
include_once '../bd/conexion.php';
$objeto = new Conexion();
$conexion = $objeto->Conectar();
$numeroEconomico = (isset($_POST['numeroEconomico'])) ? $_POST['numeroEconomico'] : '';
$marca = (isset($_POST['marca'])) ? $_POST['marca'] : '';
$modelo = (isset($_POST['modelo'])) ? $_POST['modelo'] : '';
$color = (isset($_POST['color'])) ? $_POST['color'] : '';
$descripcion = (isset($_POST['descripcion'])) ? $_POST['descripcion'] : '';
$opcion = (isset($_POST['opcion'])) ? $_POST['opcion'] : '';
$unidadId = (isset($_POST['unidadId'])) ? $_POST['unidadId'] : '';
switch($opcion){
    case 1:
        $consulta = "INSERT INTO maquinaria (numeroEconomico, marca, modelo, color, descripcion, falta ) VALUES('$numeroEconomico', '$marca', '$modelo', '$color', '$descripcion', SYSDATE()) ";            
        $resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
        $resultado->execute(); 
        
        $consulta = "SELECT * FROM maquinaria ORDER BY unidadId DESC LIMIT 1";
        $resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
        $resultado->execute();
        $data=$resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);       
        break;    
    case 2:        
        $consulta = "UPDATE maquinaria SET numeroEconomico='$numeroEconomico', marca='$marca', modelo='$modelo', color='$color', descripcion='$descripcion' WHERE unidadId='$unidadId' ";       
        $resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
        $resultado->execute();        
        
        $consulta = "SELECT * FROM maquinaria WHERE unidadId='$unidadId' ";       
        $resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
        $resultado->execute();
        $data=$resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        break;
    case 3:        
        $consulta = "UPDATE maquinaria SET estatus='Eliminado' WHERE unidadId='$unidadId' ";        
        $resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
        $resultado->execute();                           
        break;
    case 4:    
        $consulta = "SELECT * FROM maquinaria WHERE estatus='AC'";
        $resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
        $resultado->execute();        
        $data=$resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        break;
}

print json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);//envio el array final el formato json a AJAX
$conexion=null;
```

Aquí mi  HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid caja">
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12">
         <div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="tablaUsuarios" class="table table-striped table-bordered table- 
              condensed" style="width:100%">
                 <thead class="text-center">
                           <tr>
                               <th>ID</th>
                                <th>#Económico</th>
                                <th>Marca</th>
                                <th>Modelo</th>
                                <th>Color</th>
                                <th>Descripción</th>
                                <th>Acciones</th>
                                 </tr>
                                 </thead>
                                 <tbody>
                                                               
                                 </tbody>
                                 </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
          </div>
```

Acá el Resultado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]